# What might thread-safety entail in a typical storage environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, thread-synchronization

I'm [learning](https://www.acs.ase.ro/Media/Default/documents/java/ClaudiuVinte/books/ArnoldGoslingHolmes06.pdf) multi-threading in java. I wrote a simple generic storage class that always stores objects in ascending order. I now wanted to make it [thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h033e/index.html). One way (and probably the easiest way) would be:

```
// LinkedList implementation of a typical BST
class MyStorage<T> { // implements a comparable and some other interfaces not required by the MRE
    private BSTreeNode rootNode;

    // in case of duplicates, the occurrence property of the BSTreeNode is utilized
    public synchronized boolean add(T);
    public synchronized boolean delete(T);
    public synchronized boolean search(T);
}
```

storage currenty holds: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9

However, I feel this is not a good idea as it is completely acceptable for one thread to erase 6 and the other to add 8 and no matter in what order they are called or interrupted, the storage will give the correct result. I feel what is required is to perform 2 different operations on the same value exclusively.

This is what I'm currently thinking of:

```java
// same sync block for every(or just add/delete?) function
public boolean add(T value) {
    synchronized(/*some sort of mutex on the value object instead of on this*/) {

    }
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: you can create a random Object as a class variable if you intend to only synchronized block on it for add/delete function. But the go to classes for this would generally be the reentrantlock which you can try to lock/unlock instead of using synchronized block

Comment: @experimentunit1998X, isn't that basically the same thing as a synced method?

Comment: no, a synchronized method basically syncs on "this" class. Using a synchronized block on a class variable lets say `"private Object addDeleteLock = new Object;"`, you can specify that this synchronized block is only applicable for certain methods, and if you have a new object to synchronize on, it wont clash with this. Same thing with reentrantlocks, you can have multiple at the same time, and only if multiple methods are competing for the same lock will they be blocked until they can get the lock

Comment: I know the difference. What I don't understand is the statement _"if you have a new object to synchronize on, it wont clash with this."_. Do you mean to say that it'll help me create 2 different synchronizations? One with `this` and the other with `addDeleteLock`?

Comment: "it is completely acceptable for one thread to erase 6 and the other to add 8 and no matter in what order they are called" Yeah, and your current implementation allows for that. What your current implementation doesn't allow, is for two of these operations to happen *at the same time*. (Note that I'm not saying there is no finer-grained way to do this, just that what you want is already done)

Comment: @Sweeper, what I want is for them to allow `delete(6)` and `add(8)` but not `delete(8)` and `add(8)` which is what my current implementation allows too! Also,_"What your current implementation doesn't allow, is for two of these operations to happen at the same time"_ correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that kind of depend on the caller? Or do I need to override the `run` method in some way within my storage class?

Comment: You need to *precisely* specify what the constraints for `delete(8)` and `add(8)` are.  If you simply don't want them to be able to occur simultaneously, then declaring the methods as `synchronized` achieves that.  (That would make `add(8)` followed by `delete(8)` and `delete(8)` followed by `add(8)` both legal behaviors.)

Comment: In general, saying "I want to make this thread-safe" is not sufficient.  You ALSO need to specify the correctness criteria that need to be preserved in multi-threaded use-cases.

Comment: @StephenC, I believe I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471294/what-might-thread-safety-entail-in-a-typical-storage-environment#comment136577761_77471294)

Comment: I don't believe you have.  For example, you have not stated what the *correct* behavior is when `add(8)` and `delete(8)` are called simultaneously.  (And to be pedantic, a proper specification would list the formal preconditions and postconditions for every operation.)

Comment: And what does *" ... perform 2 different operations on the same value exclusively"* mean?  What does "exclusively" mean in that context.  A specification is no use if people reading it don't know what it means.

Comment: @StephenC, _" perform 2 different operations on the same value exclusively"_ literally means the same value may not be added or deleted parallely, but different values may be. I believe the correct word is MT-Safe

Comment: _"In general, saying "I want to make this thread-safe" is not sufficient. You ALSO need to specify the correctness criteria that need to be preserved in multi-threaded use-cases."_ That is exactly what has stumped me. I'm not able to understand what criterion is more correct (in a very loose sense of the word).

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him - *"believe the correct word is MT-Safe"* - No it isn't.  MT-Safe is just another word for thread-safe. It is not a specification of *behavior*.

Comment: Imagine 2 different threads both adding a different object at the same time. Your plan to have 1 lock per value means you have 2 locks, and therefore, the locks will do nothing (locks don't do anything unless at least 2 separate threads both interact with one. A single thread that locks and unlocks is a no-op). However, writing 2 objects simultaneously will result in helheloowworldorld style interspersed garbage. This trivially proves your idea just cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "BST" means "binary search tree." Is that right?

> it is completely acceptable for one thread to erase 6 and the other to add 8 and no matter in what order they are called or interrupted, the storage will give the correct result.

Could the `delete(6)` thread possibly update any link in the tree that the `add(8)` thread needs to update or follow? Or vice versa, could the `add(8)` thread possibly update any link in the tree that the `delete(6)` thread needs to update or follow? That's what you need to prevent from happening.

There's a name for your "easiest way" in which you lock the entire tree. It's called "coarse-grained locking." And what you're hoping to use instead is called "fine-grained locking." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)#Granularity When fine-grained locking is done right, then there's less contention for the locks, but there are more of them.

You haven't showed any part of your algorithm, so I can't really comment on what you might do differently, but a more specific name for fine-grained locking in linked data structures is, "hand-over-hand locking."

I think you should [search for that phrase in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hand-over-hand%22+%22locking%22).

Comment: Hand-over-hand locking is exactly what I needed. Thank you! And yes, BST=BinarySearchTree